# Mysql - Group by with Date Range

Tags: mysql

Test Sample:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_range (
  `day` DATE,
  `available` INT(11),
  `car_id`  INT(11)
);

INSERT INTO test_range (`day`, `available`, `car_id`) VALUES ('2014-11-20', 5, 1);
INSERT INTO test_range (`day`, `available`, `car_id`) VALUES ('2014-11-21', 5, 1);
INSERT INTO test_range (`day`, `available`, `car_id`) VALUES ('2014-11-22', 3, 1);
INSERT INTO test_range (`day`, `available`, `car_id`) VALUES ('2014-11-23', 5, 2);
INSERT INTO test_range (`day`, `available`, `car_id`) VALUES ('2014-11-24', 5, 2);
```

My test query:

```
   SELECT * from test_range
   WHERE day between '2014-11-20' and '2014-11-23'
   AND available > 3
   GROUP BY car_id;
```

In this case i want all cars that are available during this range, but in the day 22 the car is not available, so i want it to do not appear in the result.

For example, if i have the range between the days, 20, 21, 22 and i want an availability higher than 4 the car 1 should not appear, because in the day 22 it does not have.

How can i get only the cars that are available on all days within the given range?

Comment: You should clarify your requirements.  `car_id = 2` is not available on the 22nd either, does that disqualify it from being in the result set?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is going wrong with your current code?  What result are you getting and what are you expecting to get?

Comment: For example, if i have the range between the days, 20, 21, 22 and i want an availability higher than 4 the car 1 should not appear, because in the day 22 it does not have.

Comment: So you only want cars that are available on _all days_ within the given range?

Comment: Yes! sorry if i wasn't clear

Comment: it is still unclear what you want to do. the example is confusing me

Comment: i want to use a CAR for 3 days, if the car is not available in one day, i can't use that car. It needs to be available in the entire range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `HAVING` clause should do the trick, as long as you are able to figure out how many days are within your search range (which you should be able to do pretty easily)

```
SELECT * from test_range
   WHERE `day` between '2014-11-20' and '2014-11-26'
     AND `available` > 3
   GROUP BY `car_id`
   HAVING COUNT(*) = DATEDIFF('2014-11-26','2014-11-20')+1;
```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3989/3)

Since neither car 1 nor car 2 are available on *all* days, only car 3 (which you can see I added and made available on all days) shows in the result.

Comment: I'm not able to figure out the days, can i do it other way?

Comment: You must know the date range to be able to construct the query, right? Therefore, you can do date subtraction to get the number of days.

Comment: I have the range yes, but i have alot of cars, relationships, i don't know when they will intersect, even with Min and Max. but i will give a try one once more

Comment: I've updated my answer to hopefully help you a bit more, but I get the feeling that you don't completely understand the problem that you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

If you have unique compound index you can query simple

```
SELECT count(*) as count from test_range
WHERE day between '2014-11-20' and '2014-11-26'
GROUP BY car_id
HAVING count = 7;
```

The `7` is number of days between 2 dates. Alternatively you can do `DATEDIFF('2014-11-26','2014-11-20')`

Answer (score 0):

You would need to specify to not include cars that are unavailable on any days within the range

```
SELECT * FROM test_range WHERE day BETWEEN '2014-11-20' AND '2014-11-23' 
AND available > 3 AND car_id NOT IN 
                                 (SELECT car_id from test_range 
                                  WHERE day between '2014-11-20' and '2014-11-23' 
                                  AND available <= 3)
GROUP BY car_id
```

Comment: This will not work if the OP wants to exclude car that have no entry for some days within the date range.  For example, if a car must have an entry for _all_ days (which the OP seems to have indicated as a requirement) _and_ on for all entries `available` must be > 3, this could fail to exclude some cars that should be excluded.

Comment: I agree with that, I wrote this before csdle mentioned that the cars had to be available every day